# PHP Guzzle - redeclare issue

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, guzzle

I'm using AWS .phar SDK to putObjects to S3.  I'm using the same code on 3 other applications, but for some reason the latest one seems to fail.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Guzzle\Service\Description\ServiceDescriptionInterface in phar
```

The above error makes no sense as: the "aws.phar" is only included once; guzzle was not installed to the server, there are no interfering namespaces.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been cleared.

Supposedly AWS's phar file needs to be in the same directory where AWS is declared.  I.e. it uses sub class names relevant to their folder locations.